# STL algorithm to generate Fibonacci numbers until a certain value is reached

Tags: c++, stl

The following code will generate the first 10 Fibonacci numbers using the adjacent_difference algorithm:

```
v = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
std::adjacent_difference(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, v.begin() + 1, std::plus<int>());

for (auto n : v) {
    std::cout << n << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

> Output: 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

But what if I want to continue generating Fibonacci numbers until one with a value of (say) 4,000,000 is reached (e.g. not the fourth millionth Fibonacci number, but rather the Nth Fibonacci number whose value happens to be 4 million (or greater)).

Obviously a do while loop with a push_back would do the job, but I was wondering if it were possible to combine an STL algorithm with a back_inserter and lambda function to specify the repeat until condition (e.g. stop inserting after value 4 million is reached or exceeded)?

The problem I see is that most algorithms operate on a range, and ahead of time we do not know how many elements will be required to produce the Fibonacci number with 4 million.

Comment: It will be much easier to provide a *generator* than to try to force the use of a particular subset of the library.

Comment: Do you need to find it procedurally? You could use the [closed form equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `find_if` and a little help from boost iterator lib:

```
#include <boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

struct fibonacci_generator {
    typedef int result_type;
    fibonacci_generator() : n(0) {}
    // dummy generator
    // put the code to generate fibonacci
    // sequence here
    int operator()() { return n++; }
private:
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    fibonacci_generator g;
    int i = *std::find_if(
        make_function_input_iterator(g, boost::infinite()),
        make_function_input_iterator(g, boost::infinite()),
        [](int i) { return i > 1000000; });
}
```

A `copy_until` algorithm could be useful here to push back results to a vector, but you need to write your own.

Comment: So basically... you create a function that solves the real problem, but instead of calling it you wrap in an iterator adapter so that you can use an algorithm you don't need and a lambda... :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes :) I personaly wouldn't do it, but seems like OP can make use of it.

Answer (score 5):

Standard algorithms are there to extract implementations that are common in programming practice. This makes it easier both for you to understand the code and for the reader to understand it. Using built-in algorithms to accumulate the fibonnacci numbers up to a given value is an overkill both for you and for whoever reads your code.

Writing a 'dumb' solution for your usecase is really easy and will be easier to maintain. For instance:

```
void fibUpTo(int limit) {
  int a, b, c;
  a = b = 1;
  while (a < limit) {
    cout << a << endl;
    c = a + b; 
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int my_plus(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    if (result >= 4000000)
        throw result;
    return result;
}

try {
    adjacent_difference(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, v.begin() + 1, my_plus);
} catch (int final) {
    cout << final << endl;
}
```

That's what I'd consider a "dumb hack," but I think it will work.  If you want to pretty it up a little, make an exception class to hold the final result instead of throwing a raw integer.  And make the threshold a template parameter.

But really, don't do any of this, because it's a dumb hack: just use a "for" loop as you mentioned.